# Issue with array index out of bounds assignment

Tags: c++, arrays

I have seen several articles regarding something similar but none of them seem to help me. I would appreciate if someone could look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong here. My teacher is not helping much. I commented out lines 65 - 75 in the driver because i couldn't get it to compile with these, will need help with this as well

**ArrayDriver.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myArray.h"
using namespace std;  
int main()
{ 
myArray<int> list1(5);
myArray<int> list2(5);

int i;

cout << "list1 : ";
for (i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
    cout << list1[i] <<" ";
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter 5 integers: ";
for (i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
    cin >> list1[i];
cout << endl;

cout << "After filling list1: ";

for (i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
    cout << list1[i] <<" ";
cout<< endl;

list2 = list1;
cout << "list2 : ";
for (i = 0 ; i < 5; i++)
    cout << list2[i] <<" ";
cout<< endl;

cout << "Enter 3 elements: ";

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cin >> list1[i];
cout << endl;

cout << "First three elements of list1: ";
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cout << list1[i] << " ";
cout << endl;

myArray<int> list3(-2, 6);

cout << "list3: ";
for (i = -2 ; i < 6; i++)
    cout << list3[i] <<" ";
cout<< endl;

list3[-2] = 7;
list3[4] = 8;
list3[0] = 54;
list3[2] = list3[4] + list3[-2];

cout << "list3: ";
for (i = -2 ; i < 6; i++)
    cout << list3[i] <<" ";
cout<< endl;
/*
if (list1 == list2)
    cout << " list 1 is equal to list2 " << endl;
else
    cout << " list 1 is not equal to list2" << endl;

if (list1 != list2)
    cout << " list 1 is not equal to list2 " << endl;
else
    cout << " list 1 is equal to list2" << endl;
    */
//10% EXTRA CREDIT: UNCOMMENT CODE IF YOU'VE SUCCESSFULLY IMPLEMENTED THE FOLLOWING:
//cout << list1<< (list1 == list2 ? " is equal to" : " not equal to ") << list2 << endl;
//cout << list1<< (list1 != list2 ? " not equal to" : " is equal to ") << list2 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

**myArray.h**

```
#ifndef MYARRAY_H
#define MYARRAY_H

//#pragma once
#include <iostream>
//#include <assert.h>
//#include <iomanip>
//#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class DataType>
class myArray
{
//overload for <<
//friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, myArray<DataType>& arr);
//overload for >>
friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, myArray<DataType>& arr);

public:
//myArray();
myArray(int size);
myArray(int start, int end);
//~myArray();

//overload []
DataType& operator[](int i);
//overload == operator
friend bool operator==(myArray<DataType> &arr1, myArray<DataType> &arr2);
//overload != operator
friend bool operator!=(myArray<DataType> &arr1, myArray<DataType> &arr2);
//overload = opertator
myArray<DataType> &operator=(const myArray<DataType> &rhs)
{
    if (myDataType != NULL)
        delete[]myDataType;
    myDataType = new DataType[rhs.arraySize];
    arraySize = rhs.arraySize;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        myDataType[i] = rhs.myDataType[i];

    return *this;
}

//function
void SetNULL();
protected:
int startIndex;
int endIndex;
int arraySize;

//template
DataType *myDataType;
};

#endif

template <class DataType>
DataType& myArray<DataType>::operator[](int i)
{
if (i > arraySize)
{
    cout << "Array out of bounds: " << endl;
}
else if (startIndex == 0)
{
    return myDataType[i];
}
else
{
    return myDataType[(startIndex + (i - 1))];
}
}

template <class DataType>
myArray<DataType>::myArray(int size) :
arraySize(size), startIndex(0), endIndex(size)
{
myDataType = new DataType[arraySize];
SetNULL();
}

template <class DataType>
myArray<DataType>::myArray(int start, int end) :
startIndex(start), endIndex(end)
{

if (start > end)
{
    cout << "Invalid start position: " << endl;
}
else
{
    arraySize = end - start;

}

myDataType = new DataType[arraySize];
SetNULL();
}

template <class DataType>
void myArray<DataType>::SetNULL()
{
for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex; i++)
{
    myDataType[i] = (DataType)0;
}
}

//overload == operator
template <class DataType>
bool operator==(myArray<DataType> &arr1, myArray<DataType> &arr2)
{
bool testBool = true;

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])
    {
        testBool = false;
    }
}

return testBool;
}

//overload != operator
template <class DataType>
bool operator!=(myArray<DataType> &arr1, myArray<DataType> &arr2)
{
bool testBool = true;

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    if (arr1[i] == arr2[i])
    {
        testBool = false;
    }
}

return testBool;
}

//overload >> operator
template <class DataType>
istream& operator>> (istream &in, myArray<DataType> &aList)
{
for (int i = 0; i < aList.arraySize; i++)
    in >> aList.list[i];

return in;
}
```

Comment: The issue that I am having is that the Null function does not seem to be working. My teacher told me to add the operator= function and that messed up "list2" setting it to the last digit entered when asked to enter 5 digits.

Comment: Your assignment operator has a serious bug in the if statement - please set compiler warnings to highest. It also lacks a check for self-assignment and you have no copy constructor The easiest way to implement the assignment operator is not to need to implement them. In other words, use vector or other containers and the compiler will generate these operators for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why not ignoring warnings (or using debugger) is helpful. My compiler showed the issue (via warnings), which should be the culprit of your problem.

In function:

```
myArray<DataType> &operator=(const myArray<DataType> &rhs)
{
    if (myDataType = NULL)
        delete[]myDataType;
    myDataType = new DataType[rhs.arraySize];
    arraySize = rhs.arraySize;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        myDataType[i] = rhs.arraySize;

    return *this;
}
```

**UPDATE:** You are also assigning the array size as elements of your newly created copy. Copy actual elements.

**UPDATE #2:** As pointed out by fellow commenters, you also forgot to check for self-assignment. Check if the array pointer of your current array is equal to the one you are assigning.

you are doing an assignment instead of comparison in the first if statement. Consider doing this:

```
myArray<DataType> &operator=(const myArray<DataType> &rhs)
{
    if (myDataType == rhs.myDataType)  //CHECK IF THE ARRAY IS THE SAME (self-assignment case).
        return *this;
    // Missing '!' character here!!!
    if (myDataType != NULL)
        delete[]myDataType;
    myDataType = new DataType[rhs.arraySize];
    arraySize = rhs.arraySize;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        myDataType[i] = rhs.myDataType[i]; // COPY ACTUAL ELEMENTS INSTEAD OF WRITTING ARRAY SIZE.

    return *this;
}
```

And, to avoid such issues in the future (if your compiler doesn't pick up on issues like this, consider doing comparisons, with constant values, like this:

```
if (NULL != myDataType)
    delete[]myDataType;
```

And then your compiler will, no matter what, pick up on the issue, since it can't assign to a constant value.

**UPDATE #3:** Also, as I noticed, you are also allowing for arrays to have user defined start/end indexes. But, you would need to rethink your current approach of calculating the index at which to get the elements in such a case (where startIndex != 0). You are getting the position of element with formula: 'startIndex + (i - 1)'. But in your test case, in list3, where the range of indexes is [-2; 6), and you start your for loop, the initial index equates to -2 + (-2 - 1) = -2 - 3 = -5. I am not sure why your code isn't crashing here, but it should.

Also, to implement the comparisons operators, check if the size is the same at first, since if one of the arrays is smaller, and you are iterating through the indexes of the larger one, it should crash, when you will access the non-existing index (and to be honest, if sizes of arrays differ - they are not equal, are they?).

Comment: I changed that segment of code to add one more = sign but it did not help anything. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain why you would call `delete[]` on a pointer that you have just confirmed is null?  I wonder if @DonovanKight meant `!=` rather than `==`.   If so, then the test is actually redundant as deleting null pointer is fine and has no effect.

Comment: @M.M Oops. Edited my post. I am too used to doing checks in the following way: if (NULL == stuff) return; And, just went into automatic typing. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I tried it both ways with the == and the != and neither worked.

Comment: Also, the only warning I am getting is Warning: warning C4715: 'myArray<int>::operator[]' : not all control paths return a value

Comment: @DonovanKight Well, they all, technically, return value. But fixed that as well, and that should not be an issue. What, exactly, "doesn't work"? It works for me, when I run it (well, to be fair, I only have the code that you posted, if you added additional code - that may be the issue).

Comment: @DonovanKight Oh, I see, the comparison operators don't work! I can see the problem. Will edit the post shortly.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius The issue I am having, when you run the code, say you enter integers 1 2 3 4 5, list 2 should also be 1 2 3 4 5 but it is 5 5 5 5 5

Comment: @DonovanKight Oh, that. I also found that strange, but didn't look that closely to your code in the main, to be suspicious. And was looking for reasons for your code to crash. You were writing array size instead of actual values from rhs, into your copy (answer updated).

Comment: You forget to check for self-assignment and deleting a null pointer is a no-op anyway.

Comment: @NeilKirk That's what you get when you focus only on a single problem at a time.. Didn't even notice that. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thank you, that fixed list 2, now list 3 is throwing up variables that it shouldn't, the first list 3 should be 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 and it is showing 0 32 1 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: @NeilKirk I am not sure what you mean, I am still new to programming, I apologize.

Comment: @DonovanKight What happens if `myArray<DataType> a(10); a = a;`

Comment: @NeilKirk you are confusing me haha sorry. I did update the original code though.

Comment: @DonovanKight Apparently, this is because you allow your arrays not to be in the range of [0..arraySize), but in user defined ranges. And you need to rethink your array index adjustment algorithm. For example: list3 has indexes ranging from -2 to 5 (inclusive). When you ask for index in position number -2, you, according to the logic, ask for element in position 'startIndex + (i - 1)' which equates to -2 + (-2 - 1) = -2 -3 = -5. I am more amazed that it doesn't crash. And, why don't you use the debugger? That's what I was using to identify majority of your code issues (after the initial one).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I am not sure how to use the debugger. I always click start without debugging, never been taught how to use it. The assignment is to be able to use a user given range. The ArrayDriver.CPP was the only thing given to us besides the expected output of: list1 : 0 0 0 0 0 Enter 5 integers: 1 2 3 4 5 After filling list1: 1 2 3 4 5 list2 : 1 2 3 4 5 Enter 3 elements: 8 9 10 First three elements of list1: 8 9 10 list3: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 list3: 7 0 54 0 15 0 8 0 list 1 is not equal to list2 list 1 is not equal to list2 Press any key to continue . . – Donovan Kight 6 mins ago

Comment: @DonovanKight So, teach yourself. Why do you think that I was taught how to use it? I have a fairly good idea of what you are seeing. And you must understand, that we can't do all of your assignments. It's your assignments. You asked your question, and we gave answers of why doesn't it work (in fact, I will do one more update to update the original post of last few details), and you need to figure out how to fix those problems. Since, it is your assignment, and not ours.